# "of which" with a number – is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

Consider this sentence;

> I found 6 coins, 5 of which were rare

Is this grammatically correct? I've been using it for years but I recently realised it may not be "correct".

I put the term correct in quotes here because I accept that there are regional variations and that English grammar is consensus based, so I'm willing to accept answers which are particular to one dialect.

Comment: What makes you think it might not be correct?

Comment: I think I have my answer, but I'm not sure. I don't know if what I'm using is a parenthetical modifier. I followed the linked question but don't see any parentheses used in any of its examples.

Comment: It's fine. The relative clause is a supplement as opposed to a modifier.

Comment: Thanks. Like most people I think, I'm self taught with English so I don't know any of the actual terminology. The quality of formal English language training in England is hilariously bad.